# IOException:cannot run program:CreateProcess error=193,%1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, gradle, mingw32

I am trying to run a shell script that runs in MinGW32. Then I get the following error:

Caused by:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./myJooqGeneratorDB.sh", (in directory "C:\Users\admin\desktop\workspace\myProject") CreateProcess error = 193, %1 is not a valid win32 application.`

My `build.gradle`:

```
task createDb(type:Exec) {
workingDir("${project.projectDir}");
commandLine './jooq/myJooqGeneratorDb.sh'
}
```

My `myJooqGeneratorDb.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm build/project.db
mkdir build
sqlite3 build/project.db < res/raw/project_create.sql
```

Does someone know what it's wrong in my code?. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just fixed the problem. Instead of :

```
commandLine './jooq/myJooqGeneratorDb.sh'
```

is

```
commandLine 'sh' , './jooq/myJooqGeneratorDb.sh'
```