# Go To Declaration and Usage feature not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 ( Patch 3 ) on Windows 10.

I have tried the following steps to solve this issue:

1. Clean Project and Rebuild Project
2. Invalidate caches and Restart
3. IDE Settings -> Reset to defaults
4. Sync project with Gradle files.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Wat do you mean by "not working"? Please share logs, screencast etc.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Solved that error but currently I'm stranded in an error -> `CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: The error is too general. Context is needed. See example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885029/ioexceptioncannot-run-programcreateprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-a